# Wrong Limit with LaguerreL

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

```
Limit[(n! LaguerreL[n,-1]/(n^(n+1/4)/Sqrt[2]/E^(n-2 Sqrt[n]+1/2))-1) Sqrt[n], n->∞]
```

*Mathematica* (wrong) output

> ```
> 13/16 = 0.8125
> ```

The right result is:

> ```
> 31/48 = 0.645833...
> ```

But numerically it is computed right (after ~ 1 hour):

```
N[Table[(n! LaguerreL[n,-1]/(n^(n+1/4)/Sqrt[2]/E^(n-2 Sqrt[n]+1/2))-1) Sqrt[n], 
     {n, 1000000, 10000000, 1000000}], 20]
```

> ```
> {0.64595327485857865704, 0.64591815870538845793, 0.64590259799022250717, 
>        0.64589332088298149047, 0.64588698941420000820, 0.64588231547803760347,
>        0.64587868275613942973, 0.64587575441366589107, 0.64587332876408306831,
>        0.64587127669377150813}
> ```

I already reported this bug in 2012, but still was not fixed (in versions 7,8,9,10)
http://code.google.com/p/mathematica/issues/list
see Issue 46

For more please see my article 
"Too many errors around coefficient C1 in asymptotic of sequence A002720"
http://www.kotesovec.cz/math_articles/kotesovec_too_many_errors_A002720.pdf

A same result we get with Hypergeometric1F1[-n,1,-1] = LaguerreL[n,-1]

Comment: Hello ! While interesting and informative this doesn't really fit the format of this Q&A. It might be better if you post it directly @ Wolfram Community.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see a question anywhere, and this is supposed to be a site for asking questions…

Comment: But "Wolfram Community" website has also only "Question" section, I not found "Report Bug" section there. Where is "official" site for bugs report in the Mathematica ? I have found several next bugs (but this bug is most interesting).

Comment: I see the question: why didn't Wolfram solve the bug? Also it might be interesting information fo other users (like myself).

Comment: Vaclav, yes, it does have "Question" section, but it is not so restrictive. You just go and post something interesting you have found. Whereas here you ought to ask a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought you would like to know that this issue has been addressed in the forthcoming version of Mathematica:

```
(*In[3]:=*) mainTerm[n_] := (n^(n + 1/4)/Sqrt[2]/E^(n - 2 Sqrt[n] + 1/2))/n!
(*In[4]:=*) poly[coefs_, x_] := FromDigits[Reverse[coefs], x]

(* In[8]:=*) coefs = Nest[Append[#, 
    Limit[(LaguerreL[n, -1]/mainTerm[n] - poly[#, 1/Sqrt[n]]) * 
        Sqrt[n]^Length[#], n -> Infinity]] &, {1}, 4]

(* Out[8]= {1, 31/48, 553/4608, -(222853/3317760), 9164693/637009920} *)

(* In[9]:=*) With[{lag = LaguerreL[10^6, -1], n = 10^6}, 
   Table[{(lag/mainTerm[n] - poly[#, 1/Sqrt[n]]) Sqrt[
          n]^Length[#] &[Take[coefs, k - 1]], Part[coefs, k]}, {k, 
     1, Length[coefs]}]] // N[#, 20] & // N

(*
Out[9]= {{1.00065, 1.}, {0.645953, 0.645833}, {0.119942, 
  0.120009}, {-0.0671553, -0.0671697}, {0.0144067, 0.014387}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good report! Can you test it also with Hypergeometric1F1[-n,1,-1] yet ?

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Yes, replacing `LaguerreL[n,-1]` with `Hypergeometric1F1[-n,1,-1]` in `In[8]` gives the same result.

Comment: Fixed in version 10.2.0.0 !