# Bug in Series[Pochhammer[1+n, n], {n,Infinity,1}]?

Tags: bugs, special-functions, series-expansion

**Bug introduced after 5.2, fixed between 12.0.0 and 12.1.1.**

---

The function

```
  Pochhammer[1 + n, n]
```

tends to infinity. We have

```
  FunctionExpand[Pochhammer[1 + n, n]]
  (* (2^(2*n)*Gamma[1/2 + n])/Sqrt[Pi] *)
```

But following result

```
  Series[Pochhammer[1 + n, n] , {n, Infinity, 1}]
  (* 1 + O[1/n]^2 *)
```

is a bug! Tested under versions 10.2 and 7.0, same results.
Interesting is that

```
  Limit[Pochhammer[1 + n, n]/(2^(2*n + 1/2)*n^n/E^n), n -> Infinity]
```

is correct.

Comment: What is your question here? Have you reported this behavior to Wolfram support?

Comment: About bugs please see 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84077/wrong-limit-with-laguerrel
The bug was fixed only after I put the question here...

Comment: Question is: please confirm that it is a bug and test it in other versions.

Comment: Of course, the workaround is to use `Series[]` on the gamma function expression instead. Anyway, 5.2 does not have the bug, but 10.4.1 does.

Comment: I wonder if MMA is actually being smart, figuring out that there is no Taylor Series at infinity, and instead giving the MacClaurin series for the singuarity "at infinity".  Note that for simple poles, (e.g., Series[1/Sin[x], {x, 2 Pi, 5}]), it does find the negative power, though it doesn't include anything like O[1/x]^2.  ...just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

The bug is fixed at least since *v12.2*:

```
Series[Pochhammer[1 + n, n], {n, Infinity, 1}]
(* E^SeriesData[n, Infinity, {-1 + 2*Log[2] + Log[n]}, -1, 3, 1]*
   SeriesData[n, Infinity, {Sqrt[2], 0, -1/12*1/Sqrt[2]}, 0, 4, 2] *)

Plot[{(2^(2 n) Gamma[1/2 + n])/Sqrt[π], % // Normal} // Evaluate, {n, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can confirm that it is fixed in 12.1.1 but broken in 12.0.0 (MacOS X 10.14)

Comment: @QuantumDot Thx for checking! You can directly edit, this is a community wiki :) .