# Why do error messages show up when mouse hovers over ListLinePlot in V 13.3?

Tags: plotting, bugs, front-end, version-13.3

**New bug in V 13.3**

Wolfram support: A support case was created with the ID [CASE:**5057959**]

---

Why in V 13.3 on windows 10, when moving the mouse on top of a plot, it says there is an error? In V 13.2.1 the same code does not behave the same.

First, here is a small movies, then the code at the end.

### V 13.3

[image]

### V 13.2.1

[image]

### Code

```
d={99.5305,98.6348,98.0392,98.1481,93.75,97.7778,78.9474,83.3333,91.6667,100.}
maxNumberOfSteps=10;
g=ListLinePlot[d,Frame->True,GridLines->{Range[maxNumberOfSteps],Automatic},GridLinesStyle->LightGray,Frame->{True,True,False,False},
   FrameLabel->{{"solved percentage",None},{"Rubi number of steps","Maple"}},
   Mesh->All,
   MeshStyle->Directive[PointSize[Medium],Red],
   PlotStyle->LightRed,
   PlotRange->{{1,maxNumberOfSteps},{40,110}},
   FrameTicks->{{Automatic,None},{Range[maxNumberOfSteps],None}},
   BaseStyle->Automatic,
   ImageSize->300]
```

Comment: This is very likely related to the new `PlotHighlighting` stuff

Comment: Seems be a bug. Now only `ListPlot[..., Joined -> True]` work.

Comment: See [How to report a bug in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106232/9490)

Comment: Also happens with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249560

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
PlotHighlighting -> None
```

to prevent the feature of auto highlighting.

Or as my comment,using

```
ListPlot[..., Joined -> True]
```

**Edit**

This bug have been fixed in v13.3.1
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use `Plotmarkers` instead of `Mesh`.

```
With[{d = {99.5305, 98.6348, 98.0392, 98.1481, 93.75, 97.7778, 
    78.9474, 83.3333, 91.6667, 100.}, maxNumberOfSteps = 10},
    ListLinePlot[d, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {Range[maxNumberOfSteps], Automatic}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"solved percentage", None}, {"Rubi number of steps","Maple"}},
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> LightRed, 
    PlotRange -> {{1, maxNumberOfSteps}, {40, 110}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[maxNumberOfSteps], None}}, 
    BaseStyle -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "bug" is removed by

```
Mesh -> {All, All}
```

Generally the "All" directive was working on list output, too, where the normal input would require a directive for each  entry. There seems to be a conflict between Graphics and mouse coordinate supply by interaction now.

Comment: With version `13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)` and using `Mesh -> {All, All}`, I get the message `Mesh::ilevels: All is not a valid mesh specification.` and there are no mesh points.

Comment: I also get an error `Mesh::ilevels: All is not a valid mesh specification.` on V 13.3, so this is does not remove the bug? I am on window 10.

Comment: Does not work on Windows 11.  And the result just as set `Mesh->None`

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2950027

Comment: This answer should be removed since it (1) doesn't answer the user's question and (2) contains errors

Comment: The bug still exists in 13.3 (today), the original code is diplaying a Graphics ouptut in pink background (error) and the Mesh->{All,All} still is working. Neither  your (1) nor (2) are true. So´why do you think to remove the answer?