# Why is this product equal to zero, when the correct result is 2+GoldenRatio?

Tags: bugs, products

Consider the following product

$$
\prod _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{1-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right)^k}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right)^{2 k}}}$$

Mathematica (all tested versions) calculated it as zero, but the correct result is 2 + GoldenRatio.

```
 Product[1/(1 - ((Sqrt[5]-1)/2)^k/(1 - ((Sqrt[5]-1)/2)^(2*k))), {k, 2, Infinity}]
 (* 0 *)
```

But the numerical calculation is

```
 N[Product[1/(1 - ((Sqrt[5]-1)/2)^k/(1 - ((Sqrt[5]-1)/2)^(2*k))), {k, 2, 1000}], 20]
 (* 3.6180339887498948482 *)
```

which is the correct result

```
 N[2 + GoldenRatio, 20]
 (* 3.6180339887498948482 *)
```

Comment: You can use `s=NProduct[1/(1 - ((Sqrt[5] - 1)/2)^
       k/(1 - ((Sqrt[5] - 1)/2)^(2*k))), {k, 2, 
   Infinity}] // RootApproximant`. Use `s /. Sqrt[5] -> 2 GoldeRatio - 1 // Simplify` to put it in the form you want.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Have you reported it to WRI?

Comment: Michael, my experience is as follows. In 2012 I reported one bug (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84077/wrong-limit-with-laguerrel). It has not been fixed for several years. Only when I mentioned it in this forum (in 2015), it was relatively quickly fixed. I am therefore skeptical about this.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that the function

```
f[n_, x_:(Sqrt[5]-1)/2] := Product[
   1 / (1 - x^k/(1 - x^(2*k))), {k, 2, n}];
```

when called with `f[n, x]` returns

```
-((-1 + x + x^2)*QPochhammer[-1, x, 1 + n]*QPochhammer[x, x, n])/
   (2*(-1 + x^2)*QPochhammer[-2/(1 + Sqrt[5]), x, 1 + n]*
   QPochhammer[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, x, 1 + n])
```

which is a product/quotient of `QPochhammer` symbols with
`(-1+x+x^2)` in the numerator and 
`QPochhammer[(1+Sqrt[5])/2,x,1+n]` in the denominator.
However, when this is expanded out, and `n` is a positive
integer, then `1 - x(1+Sqrt[5])/2` appears as a factor and
when `x` is `(Sqrt[5]-1)/2` this factor is `0` and **both**
the numerator and denominator have `0` factors. Mathematica
apparently doesn't recognize the hidden `0` in the denominator.
What this means is that the use of a `QPochhammer` quotient is
valid **generically** but it is not valid if division by zero
is introduced which is precisely the case here. It is somehwat
similar to replacing `1+x` with `(1-x^2)/(1-x)`
which is valid **unless** `x==1`

Just for your information, if we define the functions

```
F[n_] := Fibonacci[n]; L[n_] := LucasL[n];
a[n_] := 2 + L[2 n + 2] - F[n + 4] - (L[2 - n] + F[n + 1])/2;
b[n_] := 1 + F[2 n + 1] - F[n + 2] - (F[2 - n] + F[n + 1])/2;
```

then `f[n] F[2 n + 2] == a[n] + Sqrt[5] b[n]`.