# Why is the convergent product with GoldenRatio evaluated as ComplexInfinity?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

It is true that the following product has a singularity for k = 1, but from k = 2 it is convergent.
We can be convinced of this by numerical calculation:

```
 N[Product[1/(1 - 1/GoldenRatio^k*(1 + k/GoldenRatio)), {k, 2, 1000}], 60]
 N[Product[1/(1 - 1/GoldenRatio^k*(1 + k/GoldenRatio)), {k, 2, 2000}], 60]

(* 167.566103786067378643031697535002496062682533360948646334201
   167.566103786067378643031697535002496062682533360948646334201 *)
```

But I discovered a bug if the product starts from 2.

```
 Product[1/(1 - 1/GoldenRatio^k*(1 + k/GoldenRatio)), {k, 2, Infinity}]

 (* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
 ComplexInfinity *)
```

Why is evaluated as ComplexInfinity ?

Comment: Likely a bug. Also `Product[(1 - 1/GoldenRatio^k*(1 + k/GoldenRatio)), {k, 2, Infinity}]` performs `Indeterminate` though `NProduct[(1 - 1/GoldenRatio^k*(1 + k/GoldenRatio)), {k, 2, Infinity}]` results in `0.00596779` so  there is no division by zero.

Comment: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206655/why-is-this-product-equal-to-zero-when-the-correct-result-is-2goldenratio/206850#206850) for a similar case. Your question is a variation on the theme.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. However, as can be seen, even this bug has not been fixed since 2019.

Comment: Repairs  of bugs take a time. It is not so simple.

Comment: To find a bug is not so simple, too. The present bug can be seen in Mathematica 8, it is at least ten year old one. We all should be grateful to people who find bugs.

Comment: As I explained in my answer to your previous question on this topic, there is no direct bug fix. There are only workarounds. An actual "bug fix" would almost certainly require drastic changes to the Mathematica philosophy.